# Python, bad practice to have same name on classes

Tags: python, django

I have multiple files like this in a django app.

```
django-app
----views
-------app_one.py
-------app_two.py
-------app_three.py
```

Inside app_one.py i have code similar to this

```
class AppOne:
    ... some methods ...

class Data(AppOne, APIView):
    def post(request):

class History(AppOne, APIView):
    def get(request):
```

In app_two.py I would like to name my classes like this (Note the sub_classes have the same names as in app_one):

```
class AppTwo:
    ... some methods ...

class Data(AppTwo, APIView):
    def post(request):

class History(AppTwo, APIView):
    def get(request):
```

So, my question is this: This works fine, I can run the server etc. But is this a bad practice? Could I run into unexpected results because of this?

The reason I want these specific names is because I use them inside Django admin for a permissions thing.

Comment: Are those views or models?

Comment: Views, I've edited to make it cleared. AppOne is just a regular python class and Data and History are Django View classes that should inheirt some methods from AppOne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views don't matter in the admin at all, so that's beside the point.

No, you shouldn't bump into any trouble; after all Django doesn't really care about your view classes' naming, it just cares about how they're hooked up in your `urls` (or if you're using DRF, based on `APIView`, your API router).

There's also nothing stopping you from inheriting things cross-app (after all, apps are just Python packages that are registered with Django) if that leads to less code and/or makes sense for you.